# Why can't I use $\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |x|$ instead of Cantor's diagonal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I know Cantor's diagonal argument works through a proof by contradiction (assume a set is countable which means there's a bijection between the natural numbers and then use diagonalization to create a new different number). This argument makes sense to me but I get confused when I think of similar arguments that do not work.

For example, instead of using diagonalization, what happens if I take the sum of the absolute values of everything in the set? Wouldn't that produce a new number that is larger (and therefore different) than everything else? However, I know this is not valid since it would offer a disproof of the bijection between natural numbers and even natural numbers.

I think my mistake is probably that I think of infinity too naively, but I can't pinpoint exactly how my thinking is wrong.

Comment: That's a good idea except that the sum of infinitely many real numbers is not necessarily a real number (because it might be infinite).

Comment: *"I think my mistake is probably that I think of infinity too naively"*, yes, you are, and kudos to you for taking this approach to the world of mathematics.

Comment: Although Cantor's diagonal argument is often (mis)presented as an argument by contradiction, especially in the context of the real numbers or the power set of a given set, it need not be done by contradiction. It is also important that the constructed object be one in the target set. "Sum of absolute value of everything in the set" may not even be defined (we can't add infinitely many things, for example), which is a *bit* of a problem...

Answer (score 6):

Let's ignore the proof by contradiction aspect (really it's a proof by *negation*, which is a different sort of thing and is constructively accepted) and focus on the pure-construction part.

Cantor does the following: given a map $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, he

1. precisely defines a new object $\alpha$,
2. shows that $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and
3. shows that $\alpha\not\in ran(f)$.

Step $2$ is usually glossed over in presentations, leading to its being ignored by students, but it is absolutely crucial. In particular, the "add up all the elements of $ran(f)$" approach you suggest fails at exactly this point (even if we ignore that it also probably runs afoul of point $1$). Similarly, if we try to apply the diagonal argument to the rational numbers, the issue is that the object we produce given a map $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ will be a real number but not necessarily a *rational* one.

---

That said, note that your "add-up-everything" idea *does* turn into an actual result *(which I'll state imprecisely since that's not really the point)*:

> No algebraic structure which has notions of **ordering** and **sums of finite-or-countable** sets of elements, which satisfies certain basic properties, can be countable.

It's just that the real numbers do not constitute such a structure.

Comment: The thing about contradiction/contrapositive/negation here, is that you still need some kind of LEM to conclude that any real number is either in the image of $f$ or not in the image of $f$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think that's true - you just need to show that $\alpha$ is distinct from each element of the range of $f$. And this is (unless I'm missing something) constructively fine. I think Andrej Bauer has some writing on this in detail; right now a quick google turns up [this twitter thread](https://mobile.twitter.com/andrejbauer/status/1392571443469246468).

Comment: Well, if my memory serves me right, there are models of constructive mathematics in which Cantor's theorem fails, for some formulation of Cantor's theorem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm pretty sure that "There is no surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $2^\mathbb{N}$" is true in any reasonable constructive system. However, you can get models with an injection from $2^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, for example based on ITTM-computability.

Comment: @Arno: Ah, thanks. That clarifies some thing in my head.